# New Magento theme from scratch [Advices for a newbie]

Tags: magento, theming

First time on stackoverflow, first time on magento... be nice please. :)

I did my homeworks, I read few articles on the Magento wiki and I searched on the website for possible answers and solutions. Let's say that I gathered a knowlegde base and... I'm more confused than before...

Ok, let's start from this, I have to apply a custom theme to a Magento installation. The design could fit in a 2-column-left template, but is slightly different.

1. The categories browsing has to be nested in the website menu positioned in the left column.
2. The My Cart (that won't be just a link, but is supposed to update as the customer adds items to it) will be positioned in the header with account links and a quick search field.

In addition, the home page (and a couple more of pages of the website) will be a mix of a CMS page and a standard Magento page, meaning that it will show the usual menu in the left column and some dynamic PHP content (I'll probably try to add the feature in the backend to manage it).

Now, the question is, should I go for the 2-column-layout already present in the Magento distribution and try to customize it according to my needs? Or shoud I try to override it, creating ad hoc `.phtml` template files and blocks?

Any suggestions regarding the mixed/dynamic homepage?

Thanks
Angelo

Answer (score 7):

Don't start from scratch, that would be an insane amount of work. If your intended design is too different from the default then consider starting with [a blank theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blank-theme.html) (all the functional parts are in place) or even [an SEO friendly blank theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/yoast-blank-seo-theme.html). Like almost everyone else you will find you can make nearly all changes with just CSS.

Comment: Wow, I'll definitely give it a try!
Thank you so much clockworkgeek.

Comment: Ok, it seems I've managed to install the SEO friendly one (the other one was not compatible with my 1.6.1 installation I guess. Still it seems to be just a cleaned version of the default theme. I think I'll get back to JakeTheFish suggestion of experimenting and see what happens.
I'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 6):

I may advice you a very good resource which has interestind materials regarding to magento:
[Alan Storm's site](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento)

Especially chapter [Layouts, Blocks and Templates](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates)

If your task is to make a design for regular shop, I would advice you to customize Magento's template. Well in some cases you would have to override some blocks. IMHO.

**UPDATE 1**

First of all, I would suggest you to create your own theme.
So make following dir's:

```
design/frontend
-yourtheme
--default
---template
---layout
```

and

```
skin/frontend    
-yourtheme
--default
---css
---images
---js
```

Set in magento's System-configuration-Design your theme as default. It will work, even if there is no files it will work, due to theme loading hierarchy.

And start experimenting. Copy some files from  base/default or default/default theme your theme, edit and see what's happens. ;)

If you are HTML-CSS designer then I would advice you to understand how XML is working, becaus for designer this is the most difficult part I think.

Seriously, practice.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually I knew about Alan's blog. The fact is that all this reading is confusing me a bit (even because often terminology is not standars and people calls the same things with different names). So I thought that the best way was starting making my hands dirty with some code, but I wanted an advice on how to start properly without wasting time.

Comment: Thanks Jake, I will start experimenting as soon as I'll finish with the article you linked before. By the way, I'm a developer, not that good and a bit rusty, but I am. :)

In the meanwhile, If anyone else has something useful to add, I'll take my lunch break in 10 minutes. ;)